# FTP manager with bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: ftp

I do a lot of daily back and forth through WinSCP which has bookmarks that are nice to have, but it would be such a quick workflow if there were a FTP app with a bookmarks toolbar like a web browser where all the bookmarks are one click away.

Does anything like this exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use the free [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org) which allows you to save credentials (and many other settings, e.g., whether active/passive FTP is preferred) in a "Site-Manager" which is accessible via an icon.

The Site-Manager is not a bookmarks *toolbar* though. There is a single icon for the site-manager on the toolbar, and when you click on it, a new window opens.

The passwords are stored in a config-file, encoded but not encrypted, on your disk, and you can retieve them relatively easily (FTP is insecure anyway so no need to encrypt FTP credentials in an XML file).

Answer (score 0):

I use MobaXterm (not for FTP only). It allows to create FTP connectionbookmarks with credentials - https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use **Beyond Compare** from [Scooter Software](https://scootersoftware.com/)  It's a file and folder compare/merge and sync utility running on Windows.  It also supports **FTP**.  I use it to sync files from my dev machine to the website.

### Comparing Folders

[image: Folder Compare]

### Comparing Files

[image: Text Compare]

### Sessions (equivalent to bookmarks), with properties on the right-hand side.

You can assign shortcut keys to every action.  For instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> opens  the sessions windows. And you can have multiple sessions open (in tabs). Normal browsers keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> work to close the tab.

[image: Sessions]

I am not associated with it, but I have been using it for 13+ years